# gradle-gae-plugin example project does not work

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle

I took some time to create a small example project that uses gradle-gae-plugin.

I based it on one of the tutorial projects that google has.

For some reason it fails to run 100% locally (the upload of order fails) and the upload to google appengine fails.

See https://github.com/oakstair/gradle-gae-plugin-tryout

Answer (score 0):

The example project works fine for me with Java 7. This is the specific version I am using:

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

One thing that needs fixing in your build script is the definition of the `gaeSdk` dependency. That may not be declared within the `gae` closure. It needs to go in the `dependencies` configuration block outside of the `gae` closure.

Running the application with `gaeRun` works fine for me. I haven't fully tested the upload. Executing `gaeUpdate` asks me for your password so I assume it's not broken. What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: I have exactly the same java version + gradle 1.6.

Did you execute "gradle gaeRun" plus tested to upload the data/orders1.xml file?

Comment: Ah, now I get it. You meant the upload within the web application. I see the error now but am not sure why it happens. Where did you get the sample source code from (please point me to the URL)?